# Facebook tab app. Hello %username message

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

we want to build a custom page with personalized hello message. 
But it seems that to get user name (or id) they have to authorize the application. It isn`t good for us (we want only to say "hello"). For example this page http://www.facebook.com/modulplan?sk=app_4949752878 displays username and link to user profile without any grants. How could it be?

Answer (score 1):

That's using FBML which is deprecated and scheduled for removal in June ( see the [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) on Facebook's site)
To achieve that now, you'd need to have the user authorise your app and pull their name from the API